# using DDE get a response from Python to VBA in MS Access

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, dde

I have a need to pass strings back forth from a python script to a VBA application running in MS Access.

Communication from VBA to Python works great!

Communication from Python to VBA - not so great great...

The code runs without error, but I only get the 1st character of the response.

EX: Python returns "Joy" VBA only gets "J"

Keep in mind what is so frustrating is I can send strings from VBA to the Python script is no problem.

The Python DDE server:

```
import win32ui
from pywin.mfc import object
import dde


class MySystemTopic(object.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.Object.__init__(self, dde.CreateServerSystemTopic())

    def Exec(self, cmd):
        print("System Topic asked to exec", cmd)


class recv_from_VBA_topic(object.Object):
    def __init__(self, topicName):
        object.Object.__init__(self, dde.CreateTopic(topicName))

    def Exec(self, cmd):
        print("recv_VBA_CMD asked to exec", cmd)
        # print('sending back responce: ' + 'Dave is really great!!!!')


class send_to_VBA_topic(object.Object):
    def __init__(self, topicName):
        topic = dde.CreateTopic(topicName)
        topic.AddItem(dde.CreateStringItem(""))
        object.Object.__init__(self, topic)

    def Request(self, aString):
        daLen = str(len(aString))
        print("send_to_VBA_topic Request Topic asked to compute length of:", aString, daLen)
        return(daLen + ' : ' + aString)


def main():
    server = dde.CreateServer()
    server.AddTopic(MySystemTopic())
    server.AddTopic(recv_from_VBA_topic("recv_VBA_CMD"))
    server.AddTopic(send_to_VBA_topic("send_to_VBA_topic"))
    server.Create('SDER_DDE')
    print('server: SDER_DDE\n Topic: recv_VBA_CMD\n Topic: send_to_VBA_topic\n')

    while 1:
        win32ui.PumpWaitingMessages(0, -1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The VBA code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function dde_send(Optional strIn As String) As String
Dim sRet As String
Dim Blp As Long
'Blp = DDEInitiate("RunAny", "RunAnyCommand")
Blp = DDEInitiate("SDER_DDE", "recv_VBA_CMD")

If Not IsNull(strIn) Then
    Call DDEExecute(Blp, strIn)
Else
    Call DDEExecute(Blp, "Greetings from VBA!")
End If

Call DDETerminate(Blp)
dde_send = sRet
End Function

Public Function dde_recv(Optional strIn As String) As String
Dim sRet As String
Dim Blp As Long

Dim vDDE As Variant, sDDE As String
Blp = DDEInitiate("SDER_DDE", "send_to_VBA_topic")
If Not IsNull(strIn) Then
'    vDDE = DDERequest(Blp, strIn)
    sDDE = DDERequest(Blp, strIn)
    Debug.Print sDDE
Else
    vDDE = DDERequest(Blp, "dde_recv test")
End If

DDETerminate (Blp)
dde_recv = sDDE
End Function
```

dde_send works
dde_recv only gets the 1st character

NOTE: I tested the Python server with this code and it works for receiving the correct string back from the server.

```
import win32ui
import dde

#apparently "servers" talk to "servers"
server = dde.CreateServer()
#servers get names but I'm not sure what use this name
#has if you're acting like a client
server.Create("TestClient")
#use our server to start a conversation
conversation = dde.CreateConversation(server)

# RunAny is the server name, and RunAnyCommand is the topic
conversation.ConnectTo("SDER_DDE", "send_to_VBA_topic")
# DoSomething is the command to execute
# conversation.Exec("Dave is Great!")

# For my case I also needed the request function
# request somedata and save the response in requested_data.
try:
    requested_data = conversation.Request("somedata")
    print(requested_data)
except:
    print('conversation.Request: exception error')
```